# Redirecting dynamic subdomain with directory structure to a single file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain name with wildcard dns active. what i want to write in htaccess is that when the user type abc.domain.com/news/news-details.php then it should send request to the file news.php with arguments val=abc. 
I have in the htaccess the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^news/news-details\.php$
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=.
RewriteRule (.*) /news.php?div=%1 [L]
```

But this is throwing a 404 error. what is the core part are the following two lines to explain

request for `www.domain.com/news/news-details.php` goes to `www.domain.com/news.php` 
and `abc.domain.com/news/news-details.php` goes like `www.domain.com/news.php?val=abc`
Please note that i am not redirecting. the urls will show as a dynamic sub domain. physically there will be no folder. all files are located in the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST) !^www\.
RewriteRule ^news/news-details.php$ /news.php?div=%1 [NC,QSA,L]
```